# changing language with setlocale on Windows

Tags: c, winapi, gettext

I have a CLI program that's using libintl's gettext, and calls setlocale(LC_ALL, "") to change output language to whatever the user's preferred language is.

I'm developing on a machine where US English is my default locale, and want to test the German output. This is easy on Linux, where I can change the language with an environment variable, like so: `LANGUAGE=de_DE ./a.out`

There doesn't seem to be an environment variable like this on Windows? The CRT reference for setlocale says:

> The locale name is set to the value returned by GetUserDefaultLocaleName.

I can find no mention of how to change that default locale for a single process. Is there even such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, the problem turned out to be unrelated to setlocale. The program was calling bindtextdomain with /usr/share/locale, which doesn't exist on Windows. Once I changed it to search for the .mo files in the right place, `set LANG=de` worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`setlocale`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=msvc-160#remarks) with supported locale string to set per process's locale.
The function [`_configthreadlocale`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=msvc-160#example) is used to control whether `setlocale` affects the locale of all threads in a program or only the locale of the calling thread.
Why don't you set locale in program?

Comment: It's not my program to modify, and I don't feel like forking it. On other operating systems, it doesn't need to be modified, because the locale can be set with an environment variable - I'm just asking if the same is possible on Windows.